# `height: auto` does not work to automatically resize header

Tags: html, css, height

I'm trying to do a simple thing in CSS

I have a `header` tag and inside that a couple of `h` tags. So, in order to have a responsive design I do

`height:auto;`

inside the `header` tag, so it will automatically stretch to contain the `h` tags. Right?

But does not work,  `header`is just a line in the top of the page. It should stretch to contain the titles, right?

What am I missing?

Is it a good practice to put CSS in the `h` tags and not style `header` at all? So `h` tags will be like the `header` in user's eye?

Thanks in advence

Check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/slevin/Fuw6x/20/)

**UPDATE** 
 Thanks everyone for the ansers . I thought GluePear's will solve the problem, so I edit my code. But nothing happend. The real file I have has 2 `h` tags inside a `header`. And then `body`, and some dive inside `body`. For some reason this not works. Header expands to the whole page now!

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/slevin/Fuw6x/47/) out

How can I fix this?

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you add `overflow:auto` to the header css it will work.

You also need to close the `<header>` tag:

http://jsfiddle.net/pvVxx/

Comment: Hi there. Is it working? Because, the background color of the header should be grey, the same color as the `h1` . And its not...They are both `#CCCCCC` but the color of the header is white

Comment: Updated my answer. There was a typo in your CSS: you had `background - color` instead of `background-color`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your anser. But there is something wrong with my file. I updated my question, if you wanna check

Comment: You forgot to close the `<header>` tag, I've updated my answer with a jsfiddle.

Comment: OH MY GOD! You are so right I just realise it right now. I did not close the `header` tag. Thanks so much for your time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear after you use floats
Here is an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/Fuw6x/28/ `clear: both;`

Read up on clear here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

Comment: Thanks for the anser. I remove the `float` but the problem remains. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I put an answer, to shortcut the problem: using float 'kills' any height calcualtion some how - this is a the best explaination i found (yes here on stack)
http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: Thanks for the anser. I remove the `float` but the problem remains. I updated my question

Comment: you had many "attr - l/t/r" instead of "attr-l/t/r" and "x %" instead of "x%" -> i corrected that and added a "h2 a" to "h2" now it looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/98YWA/4/